# How to call AvalonEdit Methods/Commands?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I am looking into the documentation of AvalonEdit - http://avalonedit.net/documentation/,
Which contains all sorts of useful functionalities and method calls.

I am not sure how to call and apply them.
An example could be

```
public static readonly RoutedCommand RemoveLeadingWhitespace
```

And I am not sure how to execute it, so it removes the trailing whitespace in my text editor instance.

I've tried with

```
avalonEditInstance.RemoveTrailingWhitespace();
```

The return type of the method is RoutedCommand,
so I also tried.

```
RoutedCommand routedCommand = AvalonEditCommands.RemoveTrailingWhitespace;
routedCommand.Execute(avalonEditInstance,avalonEditInstance);
```

What is the correct way of calling these methods, as I didn't find it in their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute commands on `avalonEditInstance.TextArea`

```
RoutedCommand routedCommand = AvalonEditCommands.RemoveTrailingWhitespace;
routedCommand.Execute(null, avalonEditInstance.TextArea);
```

It's generally the `TextArea` control that gets focussed and is doing all the command-handling.